# Launch a python script in PHP

Tags: php, python, apache, webserver

I need to launch a Python script under PHP. To launch the python script I use:

```
$mystring = system('python testpy.py ');
```

`testpy.py` is in the same directory of the php file. If the content of the python script is a simple "Hello world" it works. But if I need to launch a python script which use some library it doesn't work. For example:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python2.7
# encoding: utf-8

import sys;
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import os, site; 
help(site)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print "Hello, World!"
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

But in my browser I see:

> Help on module site: NAME site - Append module search paths for third-party packages to sys.path. FILE /usr/lib/python2.7/site.py MODULE DOCS http://docs.python.org/library/site DESCRIPTION **************************************************************** * This module is automatically imported during initialization. * **************************************************************** In earlier versions of Python (up to 1.5a3), scripts or modules that needed to use site-specific modules would place `import site'' somewhere near the top of their code. Because of the automatic import, this is no longer necessary (but code that does it still works). This will append site-specific paths to the module search path. On Unix (including Mac OSX), it starts with sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix (if different) and appends lib/python/site-packages as well as lib/site-python. On other platforms (such as Windows), it tries each of the prefixes directly, as well as with lib/site-packages appended. The resulting directories, if they exist, are appended to sys.path, and also inspected for path configuration files. For Debian and derivatives, this sys.path is augmented with directories for packages distributed within the distribution. Local addons go into /usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages, Debian addons install into /usr/{lib,share}/python/dist-packages. /usr/lib/python/site-packages is not used. A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form .pth; its contents are additional directories (one per line) to be added to sys.path. Non-existing directories (or non-directories) are never added to sys.path; no directory is added to sys.path more than once. Blank lines and lines beginning with '#' are skipped. Lines starting with 'import' are executed. For example, suppose sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix are set to /usr/local and there is a directory /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages with three subdirectories, foo, bar and spam, and two path configuration files, foo.pth and bar.pth. Assume foo.pth contains the following: # foo package configuration foo bar bletch and bar.pth contains: # bar package configuration bar Then the following directories are added to sys.path, in this order: /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bar /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/foo Note that bletch is omitted because it doesn't exist; bar precedes foo because bar.pth comes alphabetically before foo.pth; and spam is omitted because it is not mentioned in either path configuration file. After these path manipulations, an attempt is made to import a module named sitecustomize, which can perform arbitrary additional site-specific customizations. If this import fails with an ImportError exception, it is silently ignored. FUNCTIONS abs__file__() Set all module' __file__ attribute to an absolute path addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths) Process a .pth file within the site-packages directory: For each line in the file, either combine it with sitedir to a path and add that to known_paths, or execute it if it starts with 'import '. addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths=None) Add 'sitedir' argument to sys.path if missing and handle .pth files in 'sitedir' addsitepackages(known_paths) Add site-packages (and possibly site-python) to sys.path addusersitepackages(known_paths) Add a per user site-package to sys.path Each user has its own python directory with site-packages in the home directory. aliasmbcs() On Windows, some default encodings are not provided by Python, while they are always available as "mbcs" in each locale. Make them usable by aliasing to "mbcs" in such a case. check_enableusersite() Check if user site directory is safe for inclusion The function tests for the command line flag (including environment var), process uid/gid equal to effective uid/gid. None: Disabled for security reasons False: Disabled by user (command line option) True: Safe and enabled execsitecustomize() Run custom site specific code, if available. execusercustomize() Run custom user specific code, if available. getsitepackages() Returns a list containing all global site-packages directories (and possibly site-python). For each directory present in the global`PREFIXES`` , this function will find its `site-packages` subdirectory depending on the system environment, and will return a list of full paths. getuserbase() Returns the `user base` directory path. The `user base` directory can be used to store data. If the global variable ``USER_BASE`is not initialized yet, this function will also set it. getusersitepackages() Returns the user-specific site-packages directory path. If the global variable`USER_SITE`` is not initialized yet, this function will also set it. main() makepath(*paths) removeduppaths() Remove duplicate entries from sys.path along with making them absolute setBEGINLIBPATH() The OS/2 EMX port has optional extension modules that do double duty as DLLs (and must use the .DLL file extension) for other extensions. The library search path needs to be amended so these will be found during module import. Use BEGINLIBPATH so that these are at the start of the library search path. setcopyright() Set 'copyright' and 'credits' in **builtin** setencoding() Set the string encoding used by the Unicode implementation. The default is 'ascii', but if you're willing to experiment, you can change this. sethelper() setquit() Define new builtins 'quit' and 'exit'. These are objects which make the interpreter exit when called. The repr of each object contains a hint at how it works. DATA ENABLE_USER_SITE = True PREFIXES = ['/usr', '/usr'] USER_BASE = '/var/www/.local' USER_SITE = '/var/www/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

I work on an Ubuntu webserver with Apache, in mysite conf file I insert the option about cgi script:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

But no results.

Comment: Try running a script file with the python command line

Comment: Problem is not the command to launch python script: $mystring = system('python testpy.py ');   but I think there is a configuration problem of the libraries.